# Visio stencils for system architecture

Tags: soa, visio, stencils

I know there are questions related to mine, but they do not solve my problem and I cannot find anything on the Internet. I want to create a diagram of the system we created. What I need is stencils with icons for:

- website
- database
- webservice
- workflow
- wcf service (not necessarily different from the webservice stencil)
- windows service
- Active directory

I would like the webservice to have a gearbox theme in it (something like http://www.coretechnologies.com/images/alwaysup_web_service_logo.gif). Does such set of stencils exist or does everything look like it's from ages ago? (that is what I have found on the net until now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own from PNGs found on the internet. It's not a nice solution, because they are not vector graphics, but at least I could make the schemes I wanted...

Answer (score 0):

You might try this large set from MS, as it contains numerous enterprise and Azure related symbols not found in the default set provided in Visio, and not available through the online Visio feature.  The set includes SVG as well as bitmap versions.  I personally found it while looking for a Cosmos DB stencil: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41937

Comment: Welcome aboard please consider this: "barely more than a link to an external site" - https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers